# Activity not transparent while using Theme.AppCompat

Tags: android, transparency, android-theme

I have tried lots of to make activity or main layout transparent using theme defined into `style.xml` with different different attribute in theme still not working.

Only `view.setalpha(0)` that makes layout or activity is transparent, but how to possible through `style.xml`. I am using `Theme.AppCompact` for support lower version of Android device.

Also i have tried lots of SO answer but none of one is working. What i am doing wrong or any correction there? what I have done so far is as following.

Please help me to solve the issue.

**style.xml**

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" parent="AppTheme">

        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item> <!-- Or any transparency or color you need -->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="demo.intel.com.serviceprogressbarnotification">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent">


        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".TestActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Remove `android:background`, leave only `android:windowBackground`.

Comment: thanks for your answer.but still not working.

Comment: Have you applied transparent background to you root view also?

Comment: Make sure you are not applying `background` to parent of your `xml` layout

Comment: #wizard thanks brother you have saved me. i have just removed background of root layout and now its working.Thanks a lot.

Comment: #azizbekian thanks also.

Comment: Good. Either remove your question or answer it.

Comment: can anybody tell me how  can i make activity transparent using code or programatically

Comment: i have tried this code but its make activty backgroung to black  getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

Comment: #azizbekian you have any idea about dynamically make activity transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I have same case but I wanted to make my window to act like dialog and on the background of it I put my required transparency level. here is the style I used:

> ```
>  <style name="transparent_alertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
>     <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
>     <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
>     <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
>     <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.95</item>
>     <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
>     <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
>     <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">50%</item>
>     <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">50%</item>
>     <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
>     <item 
>     name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
>     <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
> </style>
> ```

and in manifest I used it like :

```
    <activity
    android:name=".PaymentConfirmationActivity"
    android:label=""
    android:theme="@style/transparent_alertDialog"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

So it did the trick for me. 
Hope so it will help for you too.